# Fetch pointer key if needed

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

I have a `PFObject` and a few of the keys contain pointers. Sometimes I'm not including these in the original query. How do I fetch these for an existing object? Do I have to form a whole new `PFQuery`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accepted answer is incorrect. The OP said that sometimes the related objects are not included in the original query, and asks if another query is necessary.

includeKey is for use in the original query. If the objects are not included, the correct approach is to use fetchIfNeeded:
https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html#//api/name/fetchIfNeeded

```
PFObject *department = user[@"department"];
// If includeKey was not used for department in the original query, department is now only a stub pointing to the actual object.
[department fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
  NSString *departmentName = department[@"name"];
}];
```

Comment: I just got around to checking this and I believe you are correct.

Comment: Is there a way to call fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock on the user object instead and still get the same result? I'm asking because if user contains many pointers (department, team, location...), it's messy to start calling fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock on each of those pointers..

Comment: @VanDuTran Not sure what you're asking, but if you have many pointers you want to ensure are included with the user object, use includeKey on the original query for that user object. [query includeKey:@"team"];

Comment: @Handsomeguy my question is that, let's say I didn't use includeKey on the original query for the user object (because I did not need them at that point in time in the app), can I just call [user fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock...] to have all the "pointed" objects filled up (department, team, etc)? If not, I would need to make a call on each of them individually.. not very efficient.. I hope you understand my question better.

Comment: @VanDuTran I am not entirely sure, but I believe you would need to call on each individually. You can't call it on the user object. This is only called on the related object you want to fetch if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Use `includeKey:` on any pointer keys you want included in the query.

```
PFQuery * query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"SomeParseClass"];

[query includeKey:@"SomePointerKey"];

[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        PFObject * firstOb = objects[0];
        PFObject * pointerObject = firstOb[@"SomePointerKey"];
    }
}];
```

If you already have an object, you can fetch the pointer object. If it doesn't have a reference to the object, you would have to stack fetches:

```
if (ob[@"SomePointerKey"]) {
    // ob already has pointer to object
    PFObject * pointerOb = ob[@"SomePointerKey"];
    [pointerOb fetchInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            // pointerOb ready here!
        }
    }];
}
else {
    // ob is missing pointer data, fetch it!
    [ob fetchInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
        PFObject * pointerOb = object[@"SomePointerKey"];
        [pointerOb fetchInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                // pointerOb ready here!
            }
        }];
    }];
}
```

Comment: Gotcha. However, this creates a separate object for the pointer object. I guess there's no way to do an `includeKey` after you already have the object, save for just re-querying with an `includeKey` and simply replacing the original object with the brand new object.

Comment: If you already have a pointer to the childObject, once you fetch that childObject's data, it should be available in its entirety within its parentOb?

Comment: @Logan Looks like it is available within the parent once fetched using this method (proven by logging the pointer's value before and after the fetch)